# Farseer: RemoveBody is not working

Tags: xna, c#, physics, farseer-physics-engine

I want to remove bodies after they touched the character(playerrect). But the bodies get not removed. I set a breakpoint in the following line but it doesn't get yellow:

```
world.RemoveBody(world.BodyList[i]);
```

What is wrong? Why is the breakpoint not getting released?

How can I remove a body?

```
bool Player_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
{
  if (fixtureB.CollisionCategories == Category.Cat1)
  {
    fixtureB.UserData = "RemoveMe";
  }
  return true;
}

playerrect = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 0.64f, 0.64f, 1.0f);
playerrect.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
playerrect.Position = new Vector2(0.22f, 0f);
playerrect.FixedRotation = true;

playerrect.OnCollision += Player_OnCollision;

reccoin = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, 0.64f, 0.64f, 1.0f);
reccoin.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
reccoin.Position = new Vector2(0.96f, 4.16f);
reccoin.IsSensor = true;
reccoin.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat1;

 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
 {
   float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
   world.Step(Math.Min(elapsed, (1f / 60f)));
   for (int i = world.BodyList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {   
     if (world.BodyList[i].UserData == "RemoveMe")
     world.RemoveBody(world.BodyList[i]);
   }

 base.Update(gameTime);
 }

//Drawing:
spriteBatch.Draw(coinSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(reccoin.Position),
                                   null,
                                   Color.White, reccoin.Rotation, new Vector2(coinSprite.Width / 2.0f, coinSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f,
                                   SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Comment: Is the collision being detected? At which point does the code start doing something unexpected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier and faster to just remove the fixture on collision, instead of looping and checking for a string you set earlier.

I would update the OnCollision function as follows:

```
bool Player_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
{
  //If category group 1
  if (fixtureB.CollisionCategories == Category.Cat1)
     world.RemoveBody(fixtureB);

  return true;
}
```

And then your Update method:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
   float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
   world.Step(Math.Min(elapsed, (1f / 60f))); 
   base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be a bad idea to remove something during the timestep? Or isn't that a bad idea?

Comment: This is fine to do afaik.

Comment: I have a problem. I'm sure that the removing of the fixture is working, but Visual Studio is still drawing the sprite. But I don't want that the sprite is drawn. How can fix this problem?

Comment: You have to make sure you go and actually prevent the sprite from rendering on XNA's side. Remember Farseer is not a rendering engine(aside from DebugView). It was not meant to handle rendering - it was just meant to calculate realistic physics.